# Non-parametric measures of covariance?

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, covariance, pearson-r, spearman-rho

We have non-parametric measures like Spearman's correlation and Kendall's correlation in addition to Pearson's correlation. What about covariance?

I guess one can normalize the variables to have zero mean and unit variance, calculate the Spearman's or Kendall's correlation between them, and then scale the result back, but I wonder if there is a more principled way when I care about the magnitude.

Comment: Variance is a parametric term. If your data consist of 1, 2, 3 and you don't know the size of the interval from  1 to 2 is the same as the size of the interval from 2 to 3, I'm not sure how you'd have variance.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Are you saying I cannot calculate variance for ordinal data? That's definitely true, but in this case I have numerical data, so that won't be a problem. However, you make me think about how should I perform the normalization: normalize to unit variance or do min-max normalization?

Comment: @Jeremy You appear to use "parametric" in an unusual sense, as if it meant "numeric" or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps I could have been clearer. :) Variance is a parameter.